# Bootstrap "min-width: fit-content;" class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Is there a Bootstrap class for `min-width: fit-content;`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<div class="card" style="min-width: fit-content;">
    <p>test</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't see anything here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/

Fast-boostrap for example has this class `.min-w-fit`

https://fastbootstrap.com/docs/min-width/

Comment: There isn't a class for everything. Make your own. Also, be sure to use the docs for your version. If you're actually on 5.0.x, consider updating as many bug fixes and new features have been added.

Comment: It does seem that `d-inline-block` would accomplish the same thing in nearly all cases.

Comment: Oh, okay... I have to tell them to implement everything then! Thanks for the suggestion. I will use d-inline-block and the latest version.

Comment: May I ask why you and others, with an insane reputation like yours, do not post an answer but instead make comments and lose reputation from chosen answers?

Comment: In this case the only answer I can really give to your specific question is "no". That doesn't provide much value to the community, nor does the question itself which could be answered by perusing one page of the docs. It should probably be closed. If you had asked how to solve your problem rather than whether your proposed solution is viable we'd have a bit more to talk about.